# Better way to import from folder in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I was writing this, and then I realized many people had this same issue and many 'workarounds' were given, but I haven't seen one that is really satisfactory.

[This answer got 1000 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995949/2076973), but it doesn't work for me (I suppose it's for python 2).

[This one also has many upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/2076973), but most of the solutions simply don't work for this layout, or it's super complicated.

Anyway, given this file structure:

```
folder/
  mylib/
    __init.py__
    MyClass.py
  src/
    main.py
```

****init.py****

**MyClass.py**:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
```

**main.py**

```py
# import sys
# sys.path.append('.') # Only works if I have this! 
from mylib.MyClass import MyClass
m = MyClass()
print(m.x)
```

Running `python src/main.py` **from the root `folder/`** gives:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'
```

The easist solution I found is modifying `sys.path` (uncommenting the code above), but it still feels a bit hacky. Alternatively, if `main.py` is on the root folder it also works, but I don't want to have dozens of files cluttering the root directory.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/2076973) says that "one should structure the files into packages", but doesn't say how that is done. Is there still no better alternative?

Comment: Add an empty file `__init__.py` in src directory

Comment: Also add `__init__.py` to their shared parent directory, might be necessary. Python will treat a folder as a path it can import from only if `__init__.py` is present in it.

Comment: Traditionally, if `mylib` is specifically for this project then it should be in `src` with `main.py` and thus directly importable. If it's meant to be shared across multiple projects it can use a structure similar to the one you have, but `src` would be a project in itself with a virtual environment that has `mylib` installed into it (possibly as an editable install for ease of modifying things). Basically, `mylib` is either part of the source for this project or it's a package of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Ether you make `folder` a real Python module or just [execute it as a module](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

```
/tmp/folder >> tree                                                                                                                                                          .
├── mylib
│   ├── MyClass.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── src
    └── main.py

2 directories, 3 files
```

Running as module (from within folder):

```
python3 -m src.main                                                                                                                                           
0
```